Solar emergency LED Night light control design: Solar panel, 5 V : 3.7 V 18650 Li-ion or similar as Vref. No negative voltage. Only GND. Which Op-Amp?
Solar charging daytime with 0 V battery output to micro LED chain.
At nightfall, solar voltage drops to 0, activating Vout: 3.7 V or alternative Lithium chemistry to power 30 ft (100×) white LED rope lights. Needed current draw around 2 A.
Cell Charging solution (TP4056 or similar) 2B bought on AliExpress or other.
Old question:
if I need to manufacture a 5 V- negative voltage, or are there Op-Amps (or other comparators to buy) with GND only? - Already answered.
Follow up question:
LM393 or similar can only handle 20 mA. Will I need to involve a power FET, or are there high current load comparators that I somehow missed while googeling?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A few U-tube lessons later:

Single supply op-amps and comparators do exist. You don't need negative voltage.
Just remember that op-amps are poor as comparators just like comparators ar poor as op-amps.

A few U-tube lessons later: The whole design problem I had seems to be simply solved by a logic level depletion mode N type MOSFET: Solar powered Gate, Battery connected to Source + Power/GND, LED chain between Drain and GND.
All aided with a few passive components for circuit and component protection.
